# how to set up unity with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I have just started learning unity for game development for Android OS. I have searched google and this website too but not found any useful solutions. So is there any step by step video or text tutorial of how to integrate Unity3D with eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the external script editor to one you like. In your case Eclipse.
This can be done this way: In Unity go to Edit> Preferences > General.
There can you change the external script editor.

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Preferences.html